# What's the appropriate method for marshalling an array of strings?

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue where I get a different memory layout when debugging with ReSharper.

I have an unmanaged method that returns an array of (at most) 7-character, null-terminated strings.  When executing this method without ReSharper's debugger, the start of the "next" string is 16 bytes later.  When executing it *with* ReSharper's debugger (via ReSharper's Unit Test form choosing the "Debug Unit Tests" option), the start is 64 bytes later.

The method signature is similar to the snippet below.  The string array is then "created" similar to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1498931/4068).

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern bool GetStrings(IntPtr sourceFile,
    out IntPtr ptrToStrings,
    out uint numberOfStrings);
```

Comment: Did I miss something? I thought ReSharper used the regular debugger build in in Visual Studio. How do you toggle with/without ReSharper debugger?

Comment: That's what I thought.  Are you perhaps referring to debugging a unit test with ReSharper?

Comment: Are you referring to debugging with the test runner?

Comment: My best guess is that your app runs in x64 mode on its own and ReSharper's test runner is x86, or vice versa.

Comment: It could be a difference between the applications Target Platform and the test library's Target Platform

Comment: @cadrell0:  Both app & test Target Platform match (Any CPU)

Comment: I'm still putting my bets on interop issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this to obtain the strings:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static unsafe extern bool GetStrings(IntPtr sourceFile,
    [Out] out byte* ptrToStrings,
    [Out] out uint numberOfStrings);


[SecuritySafeCritical]
private static unsafe string[] ManagedMethod(IntPtr sourceFile)
{
    uint size;
    byte* array;
    if (!GetStrings(sourceFile, out array, out size))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to read strings.");
    }

    string[] retval = new string[size];
    for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < size; i++, p += 8)
    {
        retval[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new IntPtr(&array[p]));
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: The array size is unknown until the unmanaged code initializes it.  It's marshalled back as an IntPtr.

Comment: Okay, then let me write something up for you.

Comment: As an IntPtr?  Why not an int?

Comment: I was overlooking the fact that your strings are probably fixed to 8 bytes in length, which makes things a bit easier.  I added a second code sample that will work if that is true.  (The first sample won't work.)

Comment: I think you've found the flaw in my code.  I'm tweaking it to fit back in my actual code.  Thank you!

Comment: Great.  I'll edit out the "dead" code. (Did I get the right bit?)