# C# dllimport of struct containing an array of strings

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke, decimal

I have a third party c dll which I want to use in my c# project. I have managed to import one method which reads the header of a file. Now I want to access the method that reads the data. I think the problem is the struct containing an array of strings so I have tried various things such as a list of StringBuilder, creating a list of strings and passing it as an array, to just creating a string array directly (as shown below). After spending a whole day on this already, I no longer know what to do anymore. I am also not sure if I can just pass a decimal array the way I do now (since it is not listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120(v=vs.100).aspx).

C header of the dll:

```
enum id_retrieve_enum {
  GET_ID = 1,
  DO_NOT_GET_ID,  // id is in file
  NO_ID_IN_FILE,
  CREATE_ID       // id is not in file
};

struct id_struct {
  char **values;                     // allocated
  int size;                          // optional: DEFAULT_VALUE = NULL_INT
  enum id_retrieve_enum retrieve;    // optional
};

int importdata(char *fullfilename, int numrows, int numcols, int startrow, 
               decimal *dataset, struct id_struct *ids);
```

C# code of enum and struct:

```
public enum id_retrieve_enum
{
  GET_ID = 1,
  DO_NOT_GET_ID,  // id is in file    
  NO_ID_IN_FILE,
  CREATE_ID       // id is not in file
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct id_struct
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
  public String[] values;
  public int size;
  public id_retrieve_enum retrieve;
};
```

dllimport:

```
[DllImport("libpandconv.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int importdata(
  String fullfilename, 
  int numrows, 
  int numcols, 
  int startrow, 
  Decimal[] dataset,
  [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref id_struct ids);
```

Init data and call method:

```
Decimal[] data = new Decimal[numpoints * highdim];

id_struct ids = new id_struct();
  ids.retrieve = (hasid.Equals(1)) ? id_retrieve_enum.GET_ID : id_retrieve_enum.CREATE_ID;
  ids.values = new String[numpoints];

importdata(inputfilename, numpoints, highdim, startrow, data, ref ids);
```

where `inputfilenam`e has already been marshalled and the `numpoints`, `highdim` and `startrow` are already returned by `importheader` method which I have already imported.

Comment: have you tried to pass a 2d char array instead of a String array?

Comment: You are going to need to use `IntPtr` for `values` and marshal by hand. A C++/CLI layer would be a possible route also. Who allocates this array of strings and how is it expected to be freed?

Comment: I attempted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498931/marshalling-array-of-strings-to-char-in-c-must-be-quite-easy-if-you-know-h) to use `IntPtr` but it did not work at the time. I am going to try that again now, thanks!

Comment: @Anne Manual marshalling with IntPtr is actually quite straightforward using the Marshal class. You will still need to tackle the issue of allocation. Do you know which party allocates and how to make the deallocation occur on the same heap?

Comment: @David I have a C++ example which also calls the C methods and here they allocate the memory before calling the method: `ids.values = (char**) malloc (numpoints * sizeof(char*));` and they also free the memory at some later point. So I am trying to do the same now by using IntPtr instead of the String[] and using `ids.values = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numpoints)`. I have never worked with the Marshal class (or dllimport for that matter) so I don't really know what I am doing so am just trying out different things. I also do not know how to make the deallocation occur on the same heap...

Comment: There will need to be two allocations in the native code. The one you have given allocates the array. But space needs to be allocated for the contents of each string in the array. You need to know who is responsible for doing that. `AllocHGlobal` is fine so long as you call `FreeHGlobal` when you are done. It's not likely that the native code is going to call the native equivalent, `GlobalFree`.

Comment: I think the c code allocates the memory for the contents: `*(ids->values + recordcnt) = (char*) malloc((strlen(*datarow)+1) * sizeof(char));` (source code of the dll). And yes, I call `FreeHGlobal` at the end :) However, I am still getting memory errors when I call the dll method.

Comment: We can't really help without your marshalling code. However, you are going to need to ask the DLL to free the strings since you cannot call `free`. Only the native code can free memory allocated with malloc. Does the DLL offer such a service. By the way, people will  only get notified of your comments if you use @username in the comment. You get notified because it's your question. I don't

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for the help! I finally got it to work using IntPtr. Another problem was that the decimal was defined in a different header file, which I overlooked and therefore couldn't use the C# decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using IntPtr instead of an array and resolving it manually?